# Can I reach the World's horizon_color in bge?

Tags: scripting, game-engine, properties

I was wondering if possible to retrieve and change World properties in-game, especially the horizon_color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you want:

```
import bge
scene = bge.logic.getCurrentScene()
# background
saveit = scene.world.backgroundColor
scene.world.backgroundColor = [r,g,b]
# ambient light
scene.world.ambientColor = [r,g,b]
```

With `r,g,b` float values from 0 to 1.

If you have mist enabled, you should also do:

```
# mist color
scene.world.mistColor = [r,g,b]
```